# What fraction of bacterial proteins are membrane bound?

Tags: bacteriology, cell-membrane, literature

[Almen *et al.*](https://bmcbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1741-7007-7-50) showed that around 27% of the human coding proteins are membrane bound.
How does this compare with bacteria such as *E.coli* or *B.subtilis* (or any other bacteria)? Is there a paper out there demonstrating this?

I assume that there would be massive variation among bacteria, so although one specific example would be enough as a ballpark, I expect that this may not represent all bacteria well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a proxy for asking which bacterial proteins are membrane-bound, we can ask which proteins harbor transmembrane domains. A popular tool for detecting transmembrane domains is TMHMM, which looks for transmembrane helices in protein sequences using a hidden Markov model.<sup>**1**</sup>

For *E. coli* strain K12, [UniProt reports](https://www.uniprot.org/proteomes/UP000000625) 4,391 protein sequences corresponding to unique genes. Of these, TMHMM predicts 1,072 proteins have at least 1 transmembrane helix (24.4%), and 775 proteins have 2 or more transmembrane helices (17.6%).  Expanding this analysis to the *E. coli* [pan proteome](https://www.uniprot.org/help/pan_proteomes), which contains 165,127 non-redundant protein sequences, TMHMM predicts 28,369 proteins have at least 1 transmembrane helix (17.2%), and 16,105 proteins have 2 or more transmembrane helices (9.8%).

For *B. subtilis* strain 168, [UniProt reports](https://www.uniprot.org/proteomes/UP000001570) 4,260 protein sequences corresponding to unique genes. Of these, TMHMM predicts 1,175 proteins have at least 1 transmembrane helix (27.6%), and 845 proteins have 2 or more transmembrane helices (19.8%). Looking at the pan proteome for this species, which contains 18,046 non-redundant protein sequences, TMHMM predicts 3,967 proteins have at least 1 transmembrane helix (22.0%), and 2,463 proteins have 2 or more transmembrane helices (13.6%).

The relative depletion of transmembrane domain-containing proteins in the pan genomes of both species relative to their reference genomes could point to a functional skew of accessory genomes towards proteins that are less likely to be membrane-associated, such as strain-specific virulence factors, antibiotic resistance genes, integrated phage proteins, and proteins involved in niche-specific metabolism.<sup>**2,3**</sup> Additionally, the relative enrichment of transmembrane domain-containing proteins in *B. subtilis* compared to *E. coli* could reflect the different membrane compositions of Gram positive and Gram negative bacteria, though it's hard to say without sampling more species.

One important caveat to TMHMM -- predicted transmembrane segments in the N-terminal region are sometimes just signal peptides. Signal peptides are likely to appear as single transmembrane domains, which is why I've also reported the fraction of proteins with 2 or more transmembrane helices, above.  A more complete analysis may run the same protein sets through SignalP <sup>**4**</sup> and cross-reference the TMHMM hits to identify transmembrane domain-containing proteins that also contain signal peptides.

Note that the cited publication by Almen *et al*. uses TMHMM and directly references the results of the original TMHMM paper,<sup>**1**</sup> which reports transmembrane protein abundance in the proteomes of several species.

> One of the most referenced papers regarding the percentage of membrane proteins in proteomes is from 2001 where the membrane topology prediction method TMHMM was applied on a number of proteomes from different species to estimate the membrane protein content, for example, *Caenorhabditis elegans* (31%), *Escherichia coli* (21%) and *Drosophila melanogaster* (20%).

---

1. Krogh A, Larsson B, von Heijne G, Sonnhammer EL. **Predicting transmembrane protein topology with a hidden Markov model: application to complete genomes**. *J Mol Biol*. 2001 Jan 19;305(3):567-80.
2. Kung VL, Ozer EA, Hauser AR. **The accessory genome of Pseudomonas aeruginosa**. *Microbiol Mol Biol Rev*. 2010 Dec;74(4):621-41.
3. Álvarez VE, Quiroga MP, Galán AV, Vilacoba E, Quiroga C, Ramírez MS, Centrón D. **Crucial Role of the Accessory Genome in the Evolutionary Trajectory of *Acinetobacter baumannii* Global Clone 1**. *Front Microbiol*. 2020 Mar 18;11:342.
4. Nielsen H, Brunak S, von Heijne G. **Machine learning approaches for the prediction of signal peptides and other protein sorting signals**. *Protein Eng*. 1999 Jan;12(1):3-9.

Comment: A very thorough answer! Thanks!

Comment: It's interesting how much discrepancy there is between modern uniprot annotation and the original TMHMM paper.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the values for E. coli, 24% vs. 21%?  I haven't read the original TMHMM paper in detail, but the difference may be due to different inputs (was a complete E. coli proteome available in 2001? Or perhaps a different strain) or differences in TMHMM parameters.

Comment: Yes I realise my comment was misleading. I am actually shocked that they are so close even 20 years apart!